# MySQL changes UTF-8 to ASCII-8BIT

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, utf8-decode

I've this scenario.

A movie title:

```
$ title = "La leyenda de Osaín"
```

With this encoding:

```
$ title.encoding.name
>> UTF-8
```

I then saves it to the database.

```
$ movie = Movie.create!(:title => title)
```

Then I try to get the movie.

```
$ Movie.find(movie.id).title.encoding.name
>> "ASCII-8BIT"

$ Movie.find(movie.id).title
>> "La leyenda de Osa\xC3\xADn"
```

All other movies works that does not contain special characters like `í` and `û`.

This is my database.yaml file:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: development
  username: linus
  password: my_password
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
  encoding: UTF8
```

I'm getting the right sort of data when using `forced_encoding`.

```
$ Movie.find(movie.id).title.force_encoding("UTF-8")
>> "La leyenda de Osaín"
```

I'm using Rails 3.0.5.rc1 with MySQL 14.14.

Anyone knows what the problem may be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.
Now I'm using the newer `mysql2` gem.

I replaced `gem "mysql"` with `gem "mysql2"` inside the Gemfile.

Then I changed the *database adapter* inside the database.yaml file.

From:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: development
  username: linus
  password: my_password
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
  encoding: UTF8
```

To:

```
  development:
    adapter: mysql2
    database: development
    username: linus
    password: my_password
    socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
    encoding: UTF8
```

I think this was the deal breaker in my case:

*Taken from [Github MySQL2](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2)*

> [...]It also forces the use of UTF-8 [or binary] for the connection [and all strings in 1.9[...]

Answer (score 0):

According to [this link](http://overooped.com/post/100354794/ruby-script-generate-scaffold-types), rails scaffolding creates varchar(255) columns in mysql. [The mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html) says the following about varchar(255):

> For example, a VARCHAR(255) column can
>   hold a string with a maximum length of
>   255 characters. Assuming that the
>   column uses the latin1 character set
>   (one byte per character), the actual
>   storage required is the length of the
>   string (L), plus one byte to record
>   the length of the string.

My guess is that the column type in the database doesn't support characters that are represented by more than one byte. [This link](http://oldwiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/HowToUseUnicodeStrings) has more information about common pitfalls  in rails when dealing with unicode strings and more specifically, it says you need to create your database as utf8 like so:

```
CREATE_DATABASE my_web_two_zero_development DEFAULT CHARSET utf8;
```